# Notice: Undefined index: action

Tags: wordpress

This happened with my theme after I've updated WP to the latest version. 
The url is : http://www.movie-galaxy.com

Notice: Undefined index: video_width in /home1/djandrei/public_html/movie-galaxy.com/wp-content/themes/DarkTheme/functions.php on line 507

Notice: Undefined index: video_height in /home1/djandrei/public_html/movie-galaxy.com/wp-content/themes/DarkTheme/functions.php on line 508

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/djandrei/public_html/movie-galaxy.com/wp-content/themes/DarkTheme/functions.php:507) in /home1/djandrei/public_html/movie-galaxy.com/wp-admin/post.php on line 2

```
add_action('publish_post', 'ys_video_add_post_meta');
function ys_video_add_post_meta($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_portal', $_POST["video_portal"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_id', $_POST["video_id"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_width', $_POST["video_width"]);  
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_height', $_POST["video_height"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_thumbnail', $_POST["video_thumbnail"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_thumbnail_small', $_POST["video_thumbnail_small"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_movie_featured', $_POST["movie_featured"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_dvd_downurl', $_POST["video_dvd_downurl"]);

    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_featured_prcture', $_POST["featured_prcture"]);
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_featured_prcture_small', $_POST["featured_prcture_small"]);

    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_flv_url', $_POST["flv_url"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your POST data if its set.

```
 if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "video_thumbnail_upload_submit") {
```

Comment: This worked, but now I get another error :(.Notice: Undefined index: video_width in /home1/djandrei/public_html/movie-galaxy.com/wp-content/themes/DarkTheme/functions.php on line 507
update_post_meta($post_ID, '_video_height', $_POST["video_height"])

Comment: We would need to see more code to check that error. but my guess would be that trying the same thing, wrapping it round an `isset()`

Comment: whats the problem to think? Thats are basics. Use `isset()` to check **all** you POST variables